# Perl: Remove all non-ascii characters except specific ones

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, regex-negation, emoticons

I want to remove all non-ASCII characters except the [Unicode emoticons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons#ref_U1F600_as_of_Unicode_version) from a text file. I am using following command which will remove all non-ASCII characters.

```perl
perl -i.bak -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g'
```

Can this command be modified which will exclude emoticon characters?

**EDIT:**

Sample input: `Good morning! #Happy #StPatricksDay ♣♥`

Sample output: `Good morning! #Happy #StPatricksDay`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify range in Perl like this:

```
s='Good morning! #Happy #StPatricksDay ♣♥'

echo "$s" | perl -C -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]+//g'
Good morning! #Happy #StPatricksDay
```

[Reference: Unicode block for emoticons](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/emoticons/index.htm)

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. I had actually made this regex working in PHP long back but couldn't make it work in Perl (due to my limited Perl knowledge). Finally found this `-C` flag to make it work in Perl also :)

Comment: @anubhava, I'd be interested in your feedback on the \p{...} and \N{...} solution below. I just pulled it from manual reading as I didn't have any unicode test data to test against, but you seem to have a good handle on using unicode in regex - can you comment on it?

Answer (score 0):

Just extend the characters you want to exclude to include the emoticons:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]\p{block:Emoticons}\N{U+2639}\N{U+263A}\N{U+263B}]//g'
```

---

### Edit

After a lot of messing around and trying different switches I found a combination that works with the \p{block...} and \N{U+xxxx} type of regexes.

```
 perl -CS -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]\p{block:emoticons}\N{U+2639}-\N{U+263B}]//g'
```

Do note that your text has to be in utf-8 for this to work (at least on my cygwin setup).

Comment: Can we not include it as a range? Including every character's code is a tedious way. In the emoticons' case there are 80 unicodes. Definitely not comfortable.

Comment: I included everything in the emoticons block in a single \p{...}. You could avoid specifying the u+263A by replacing it with a range and save a single character.

Comment: I am not really sure how do I do that. Not much familiar with scripting. Also I was referring to the second table in the link I mentioned which has 80 emoticons. Can you please modify the command? Sorry for trouble.

Comment: Erm... Did you try my code? Or are you just assuming it doesn't work?

Comment: First this answer doesn't deserve -1 so my +1, but I'm not sure why `\N{U+2639}\N{U+263A}\N{U+263B}` are needed here as `s/[^[:ascii:]\p{block:Emoticons}]+//g` should have been enough.

Comment: I wasn't asking for the upvote, but thanks. In op question he has a link that differentiates btwn the emoticon block & these other 3. I don't know much about Unicode so I just took it at face value and dealt with what appeared to be 2 separate ranges.

Comment: Made a final (?) edit which gives the `-CS` switch allowing these particular perl unicode options to be used.